# Using google maps google-maps-react npm package with react-intersection-observer in order to increase lighthouse score

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, gatsby

I am trying to improve my lighthouse score for a Gatsby site I have been building. One of the things it asks me to do is Defer offscreen images which I have with done with the gatsby image plugin. However google maps is loading images it is asking to be deferred because it is way in the footer. I am using this npm package to load the map https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react

So I attempted to use the npm package `react-intersection-observer` and to show/hide the whole map component when it is in/not in view.

The issue I am running into is this improves my lighthouse score by about 5 points. But **the map no longer loads with coordinates I entered** in the component it defaults to sanfransico. I assume this is because it is being loaded late. What is the solution to fixing this?

Here is my Hook Code

```
//**********Google Maps Variables*****/

const [ref, inView, entry] = useInView({
  /* Optional options */
  threshold: 0,
})

const style = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '400px',
  position: 'relative',
}

const coords = { lat: 53.541581, lng: -113.295608 };




//**********Google maps varaibles end*** */
```

Here is my component code

```
      <Footer ref={ref} className="copyright">

        {inView &&

        <GoogleMap >
        <Map 
          google={window.google} 
          style={style} 
          containerStyle={style}
          center={{
            lat: 53.541581,
            lng:-113.295608
          }}
          zoom={12}
          mapTypeControl={false}

        >
          <Marker
          title={'Glen Alen Recreation Center'}
          name={'GARC'}
          position={{lat: 53.530358, lng: -113.282250}} />
          <Marker
          title={'Millenium Place'}
          name={'Millenium'}
          position={{lat: 53.559414, lng: -113.314161}} />
            <Circle
        radius={3900}
        center={coords}
        strokeColor='transparent'
        strokeOpacity={0}
        strokeWeight={5}
        fillColor='#30cefd'
        fillOpacity={0.2}
      />
          </Map>
        </GoogleMap>


       }

      </Footer>
```

**Update**

I tried moving the coordinates variable directly into the component and that still made no difference, hmm...

**update #2**

So my marker and circle show up if I navigate to them, but the default start position center lat, and lng are incorrect when using this intersection observer, If I remove the inView it is correct.

**update #3**

The last thing I tried was to load the map from props like it did in the example because I am using window. I tried this `<Map google={props.google}>`. I remove the `this` because props was available on it's own from the functional component. However props exists as an object but props.google does not so it just loads endlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using this npm package instead and it worked better as far as I can tell https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react